# Memory Profiling Existing Process in VS2012

Tags: memory, memory-management, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I am not able to profile memory allocation using the VS 2012 built-in profiler when connecting to an existing web application process.

When I Start profiling and let it launch the process it works fine, but if I try and attach to an existing process it reverts to CPU sampling instead of memory allocation. There is no warning that this is going to happen.

Does anyone know of a reason why this would be the case?

#### Update

I'm willing to accept that this is a limitation of the profiler (although letting me know that it is falling back this to this functionality would be nice). There are ways around it.

1. Use a different profiler. I used [this one](http://memprofiler.com/) and can recommend it.
2. Profile from the start and filter results.

I've certainly moved on.

Comment: It is pretty unclear to me how you intended to tell the profiler to track memory instead of cycles when you use Profiler + Attach.  I would just stop assuming that it can track memory allocation for a process that already has allocated a bunch of objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a limitation of the profiler. I'm sure other profilers can do this if you really need it.

The built in VS 2012 profilers are great for basic needs but for anything advanced I would go for something else.

Many of the more advanced profilers are not free, but often have a trial period. This is a good one in my opinion.

[.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) but SciTech Software